# show nested unordered list horizontally

Tags: css

I have a nested unordered list and I have to show them horizontally.
This is a link
`enter code here`    [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/urvinit/02rg49q1/)
Currenly it is showing first link in different line

but I want to display as :
Home   News   Contact   About

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the display to inline-block in `li a`, that will allow them to stack horizontally.

```
li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

To reverse the order use `float:right;`

Comment: Btw, this reverses the order of the elements, i would suggest Makois07 solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same as in the link.. then just remove the second ul tag which is before News li

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is flexbox, if the element has a style `display: flex`, you can define the direction of each items inside it (horizontal/ vertical).try this:

```css
.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
    display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<ul >
  <li class="main_menu"><a href="#home">Home</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[This link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) will explain a lot about flexbox.

Hope it helps